# How to elegantly split strings in half by word count?

Tags: r, string, split, tidyverse, stringr

I need to split strings in half by word count (when there's an odd number of words, the middle word should appear in both the left and right side). I also need to know which side each string came from.

```
my_question <- data.frame(string_id = c(001, 002, 003), 
    string = (c("how do I split", "how do I split this", "how do I split this string")))

my_answer <- data.frame(string_id = c(001, 002, 003, 001, 002, 003), 
    string = (c("how do", "how do I", "how do I", "I split", "I split this", "split this string")), 
     side = c("R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L"))
```

I prefer working with *stringr/tidyverse/hadleyverse*.

Comment: And you have tried....

Comment: Step 1 split using `strsplit`. Step 2 create vectors of indices 1:n/2 and n/2:n where n is the length of result from step 1. The first indices make the left side, the second in the right.  Use `paste` with `collapse=' '` to put the sides back together.  Try it and then if you have trouble, ask a more specific question.

Comment: Also, check out `?strwrap` and `library(stringr); ?str_wrap` to see how text wrapping has already been implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write some helper functions to make this easier

```
library(tidyverse)
word_split <- function(x, side="left", sep=" ") {
  words <- strsplit(as.character(x), sep)
  nwords <- lengths(words)
  if(side=="left") {
    start <- 1
    end <- ceiling(nwords/2)
  } else if (side=="right") {
    start <- ceiling((nwords+1)/2)
    end <- nwords
  }
  cw <- function(words, start, stop) paste(words[start:stop], collapse=sep)
  pmap_chr(list(words, start, end), cw)
}
left_words <- function(..., side) word_split(..., side="left")
right_words <- function(..., side) word_split(..., side="right")
```

Then we can use more traditional pipe chain to share the result you want

```
my_question %>% mutate(L=left_words(string),
                       R=right_words(string)) %>%
  select(-string) %>% 
  gather(side, string, L:R)
```

which results in

```
  string_id side            string
1         1    L            how do
2         2    L          how do I
3         3    L          how do I
4         1    R           I split
5         2    R      I split this
6         3    R split this string
```

Comment: That's basically what I had in mind, but I was hoping to see some effort from the OP.  We keep saying "SO is not a code-writing service," but then our generosity gets the better of us.

Comment: True. But at least it had a reproducible example with desired output. That goes a long way in my book.